# Command line command to read Oracle Database export Success Message In log File

Tags: oracle, linux, scripting, unix, bash

We have several oracle 19c servers with daily exports. I would like to find a way to run a command to read the export log file to find the success message for the day. e.g. I would like to putty into the linux server have a command I can copy and paste that will read the daily export log file and tell me in one command/output that the export was successful or not? or any better ideas to automate reporting that daily exports are successful on 40+ servers?

Comment: Take a look at `ansible`. This is the kind of automation it was designed for.

Answer (score 0):

Assume that you always start your export log files with 'expdp_' and always end them with '.log'.  Then

```
egrep -c '(^Job)(?!(successfully))' expdp_*.log
```

will give you a listing of the log filenames and the number of times 'Job' but not 'successfully' occured in that file.  Get a zero count and the export was successful, get a non-zero count and the export had a problem.

Answer (score 0):

I admit that it is not a command line solution but datapump has control tables and these could be analyzed with SQL